# `exec.Command()` produces no output when running `kcat`

Tags: docker, go, kcat

I need to wrap `kcat` in a Go function to read a series of topic messages, so thought to use `exec.Command()` for this is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("kcat", "-b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092", "-t messages", "-o 11000", "-c 11333")

    fmt.Println("Command String:", cmd.String())

    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Accessing kafka topic messages ", err.Error(), string(out))
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Result Length:", len(out))

    fmt.Println("Result Content:", string(out))

}
```

However, this returns only the first line of the `kcat` output:

```
/app/tools # ./five
Command String: /usr/bin/kcat -b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t messages -o 11000 -c 11333
Result Length: 58

Result Content: % Auto-selecting Producer mode (use -P or -C to override)
```

(NOTE: I'm running this within a docker container, however I don't think it makes a difference)

However, this works fine when run directly from the CLI:

```
/app/tools # 
/app/tools # kcat -b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t messages -o 10 -c 15
% Auto-selecting Consumer mode (use -P or -C to override)
%4|1640957136.462|OFFSET|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: messages [1]: offset reset (at offset 10) to END: fetch failed due to requested offset not available on the broker: Broker: Offset out of range
%4|1640957136.483|OFFSET|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: messages [2]: offset reset (at offset 10) to END: fetch failed due to requested offset not available on the broker: Broker: Offset out of range
[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"9266","Time":"9266","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"1547","Time":"1547","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"9179","Time":"9179","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"8740","Time":"8740","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"9318","Time":"9318","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"1743","Time":"1743","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]
```

There seems to be something unique about the `kcat` command which breaks `exec.Command()` in Go.

Questions:

- Is there any other way I could achieve the same effect in Go?
- Is this perhaps an issue with the way I'm using `exec.Command()`

Ideally, I can use the the `kcat` command in this case as I'd like to avoid using segmentios `kafka-go` library in this instance.

[EDIT]

- Separating the arguments (as suggested by @onecricketeer):

```
cmd := exec.Command("kcat", "-b", "kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092", "-t", "messages", "-o", "11000", "-c", "11333")
```

Result (same error):

```
/app/tools # ./code
Command String: /usr/bin/kcat -b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t messages -o 11000 -c 11333
Result Length: 58
Result Content: % Auto-selecting Producer mode (use -P or -C to override)
```

- Using BASH as the shell (suggested by maxm):

Same result, i.e only the first line of the kcat output is reported:

```
/app/tools # ./code
Command String: /bin/bash -c kcat -b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t messages -o 11000 -c 11333
Result Length: 58
Result Content: % Auto-selecting Producer mode (use -P or -C to override)
```

[EDIT]

NOTE: However, when I use Python's shell execution mechanism, it works fine, which leads me to wonder if there is something defective about Gos shell handling features:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["kcat","-b","kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092","-t","messages","-o","1", "-c", "11"], 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           universal_newlines=True)

while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    print(output.strip())
    # Do something else
    return_code = process.poll()
    if return_code is not None:
        print('RETURN CODE', return_code)
        # Process has finished, read rest of the output 
        for output in process.stdout.readlines():
            print(output.strip())
        break
```

Results:

```
/app/tools/python # python3 code.py 
% Auto-selecting Consumer mode (use -P or -C to override)
%4|1641004616.232|OFFSET|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: messages [2]: offset reset (at offset 1) to END: fetch failed due to requested offset not available on the broker: Broker: Offset out of range
%4|1641004616.236|OFFSET|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:main]: messages [1]: offset reset (at offset 1) to END: fetch failed due to requested offset not available on the broker: Broker: Offset out of range
[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"4512","Time":"4512","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

RETURN CODE 0
[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"2388","Time":"2388","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"8707","Time":"8707","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"1643","Time":"1643","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"2421","Time":"2421","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"7520","Time":"7520","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"1258","Time":"1258","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"1457","Time":"1457","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"2907","Time":"2907","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"9266","Time":"9266","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]

[{"Name":"newOrder", "ID":"1547","Time":"1547","Data":"new order", "Eventname":"newOrder"}]
```

Comment: What happens when you run the command `kcat "-b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092" "-t messages" "-o 11000" "-c 11333"` (with the quotes) from the CLI?

Comment: @BMitch, It doesn't seem to like it: ```/app/tools/ten # kcat "-b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092" "-t messages" "-o 11000" "-c 11333" 
% Auto-selecting Consumer mode (use -P or -C to override)
% ERROR: Topic  messages error: Broker: Unknown topic or partition
```

Comment: Any particular reason to shell out to `kcat`, instead of using a Go-native Kafka client?

Comment: @DavidMaze - I thought it would be a fast solution for a quick PoC. However, it turned out not to be as convenient as it seemed on the surface. However, it is of interest why `exec.Command` doesn't work in this case ...

Comment: It'll work fine if you separate the arguments correctly... Note that your go app would need to be deployed to a machine that has kcat on its PATH. If that's not guaranteed, you're better off using a native client, which doesn't mean using the one you've mentioned as there are at least 2 others

Comment: @OneCricketeer,@BMitch - I've tried the different forms for the command arg specification - they have the same result. Updated OP.

Comment: You should comment on the answer below if it doesn't work, but as the output says, you forgot `-C`, and the default is producer mode

Comment: @OneCricketeer - the "-C" doesn't make a difference either way, in both modes it consumes messages when run  directly outside of golang. It's only when attempting to wrap this command with exec.Command() that things go awry. Strtangely, if i do this in python (see updated OP) this works fine.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - turns out the `-C` flag makes a difference in Go `exec.Command()` (but nowhere else, python or bash). So now it works with  `exec.Command()`. Feel free to put this forward as the answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the output says, producer mode is being auto selected

Try using consumer mode with separated arguments

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("kcat", "-C", "-b", "kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092", "-t", "messages", "-o", "11000", "-c", "11333")
```

Answer (score 1):

The go command:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("kcat", "-b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092", "-t messages", "-o 11000", "-c 11333")
```

is the same as the shell command:

```sh
kcat "-b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092" "-t messages" "-o 11000" "-c 11333"
```

You need to separate your arguments, the same as the shell is doing for you on every space by default:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("kcat", "-b", "kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092", "-t", "messages", "-o", "11000", "-c", "11333")
```

Comment: You could also do `exec.Command("bash", "-c", "kcat -b kafka.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092 -t messages -o 11000 -c 11333")` if bash is available.

Comment: Unfortunately these formats have the same result @BMitch.